# How do you use a string as a method name?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I would like to define a method using string elements in an array, eg:

```
ARRAY = ["name1", "name2"]
ARRAY.each do |k|
  def k?
    self.attribute == k
    #or whatever else in here
  end
end
```

so that I could do the following:

```
article.name1? #would return true of article.attribute == "name1"
```

Is something like this possible?

Obviously this is just a simple example of one thing I might do with, but what I'm really getting at here is how to assign the method name based off a string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need [`Module#define_method`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html#method-i-define_method). Check this out:

```
class Foo
  attr_accessor :attribute

  ARRAY = ["name1", "name2"]
  ARRAY.each do |k|
    define_method "#{k}?" do
      self.attribute == k
    end
  end
end

f = Foo.new
f.attribute = 'name1'

f.name1? # => true
f.name2? # => false
```

Answer (score 0):

U can use define_method (meta programming ) to achieve this.

```
  %w(name1 name2).each do |meth|
  define_method(meth) { self.attribute == k }
  end
```

Comment: You should explain how, with a small sample demonstrating it.